# Command pip install --upgrade pip setuptools failed with exit code 1: Session venv failed

Tags: python, anaconda, virtualenv

Windows 10

1. I originally installed the Anaconda distribution.
2. I installed nox and invoke using pip from the Anaconda prompt.
3. I did all my work in the Anaconda prompt and everything worked.
4. I needed to do some more testing and also needed a Python developer environment that mirrored what other developers in my team use (they don't use Anaconda) so I uninstalled the Anaconda distribution using 'Add or Remove Programs'.
5. I installed Python from python.org.
6. I ran into errors when trying to repeat my past workflow. I managed to fix some of them by uninstalling the packages I had installed using Anaconda prompt (nox and invoke) and reinstalling using the new Python distribution but I still have one problem shown in step 7.
7. ```
   C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\projectname>inv
   Running session venv
   Re-using existing virtualenv at .\venv.
   pip install --upgrade pip setuptools
   Command pip install --upgrade pip setuptools failed with exit code 1:
   Session venv failed.
   ```
8. For background, invoke calls the following nox script

```
def venv(session):
    """Setup the developer environment."""
    # Install dependencies.
    session.install("--upgrade", "pip", "setuptools")
    session.install("-r", "requirements-dev.txt")
    session.install("-e", ".")
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by deleting the virtual environment directory and running the `inv` command again. Since the virtual environment directory had been created with Anaconda, I assume that some of the scripts in it were pointing to the Anaconda distribution's files and that is where the error was coming from.